# Validation error: There are unrecognized header names. Check documentation for allowed header names

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-translate

I am getting the validation error during custom vocabulary creation in Amazon transcribe service

I have created below text file to configure custom vocabulary. I am getting this validation error.

> Validation error: There are unrecognized header names. Check
>   documentation for allowed header names

```
PhraseTABSoundsLikeTABIPATABDisplayAs
Los-AngelesTABTABTABLos Angeles
F.B.ITABTABɛ f b i aɪTABFBI
EtienneTABeh-tee-enTABTAB
```

I followed [Custom Vocabularies - Amazon Transcribe](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transcribe/latest/dg/how-vocabulary.html#create-vocabulary-table) to prepare text file.

Comment: To test this, I tried creating a vocabulary file as described on that page (inserting tab characters) and it gave me the error _"The provided terminology file contains an unsupported source language (line 1), or the file format is incorrect"_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for this issue.

We should not mention the TAB word. just we need to give the tab key space.Or else You can directly copy from spreadsheet and past it in text file.

Below is my example text file

```
Phrase  SoundsLike  IPA DisplayAs
Like-Sina-Parole    lie-sin-oh-prel     Lisinopril
Oxy-code-on oxy-code-own        Oxycodone
```

Comment: It is still not working, I copy pasted the above text and it still fails.